# Line break before headings (<h2>) appears from nowhere

Tags: html, editor, content

So, in the database row i've the following html code in post_content:

```
Solo pochi giorni fa, esattamente il 15 marzo, è stato presentato durante l'ultima edizione del SXSW Online un suggestivo cortometraggio intitolato <em>Don't Peek - Animal Crossing Horror Short</em> diretto da Julian Terry.
<ul>
    <li><strong>LEGGI ANCHE: </strong><h2 class="h2-link-correlati"><h2 class="h2-link-correlati"><a href="https://videogiochi.badtaste.it/articoli/animal-crossing-new-horizons-e-al-primo-posto-tra-i-videogiochi-piu-venduti-del-2020-di-amazon-uk-e-us/" rel="bookmark">Animal Crossing: New Horizons è al primo posto tra i videogiochi più venduti del 2020 di Amazon UK e US</a></h2></h2></li>
</ul>
E ora, secondo quanto riportato da <a href="https://deadline.com/2021/03/timur-bekmambetov-sxsw-short-dont-peek-feature-horror-film-julian-terry-1234716264/">Deadline,</a> <strong>Timur Bekmambetov</strong> (<em>Wanted</em>, <em>Hardcore Henry</em>) sarebbe già pronto a realizzare un film horror tratto proprio dal cortometraggio sopracitato.
```

As you can se there is no line break/br before the .

BUT

In frontend, and in backend (when editing the post), the line break appears. Like new line in the editor and like a 
 in frontend.

[image]

[image]

How is it possible?

---

**EDIT**:

it seems to be related to the **wpautop** filter (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/) that made this wonderful thing: adding a line break before and after every html block

```
$allblocks = '(?:table|thead|tfoot|caption|col|colgroup|tbody|tr|td|th|div|dl|dd|dt|ul|ol|li|pre|form|map|area|blockquote|address|math|style|p|h[1-6]|hr|fieldset|legend|section|article|aside|hgroup|header|footer|nav|figure|figcaption|details|menu|summary)';

// Add a double line break above block-level opening tags.
$pee = preg_replace( '!(<' . $allblocks . '[\s/>])!', "\n\n$1", $pee );

// Add a double line break below block-level closing tags.
$pee = preg_replace( '!(</' . $allblocks . '>)!', "$1\n\n", $pee );
```

My solution was this, but it's pretty ugly:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
$br = false;
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {
    return wpautop( $content, false );
}, 10 );
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the heading outside of the unordered list? It's an odd thing to do that doesn't make a lot of sense semantically, so I'm not surprised you got unusual results

Comment: Yes, but as i wrote there is a filter (on the_content) that add extra line before and after certains html tags. Anyway, i know it make no sense to have a <h2> on a <li>, but our seo manager said that is good if that links are related to the content. 

Comment: pretty sure it's going to fail HTML validation, your SEO manager sounds like they're making stuff up. You're mixing up inline and block level items in a way you're not supposed to, `wp_autop` was never meant for that, that's why a `<br>` got added, ideally it should have been able to insert a paragraph tag but that doesn't make sense here. You'll find the browser itself will try to do similar things assuming the markup is invalid and trying to be helpful